# SAS modify tie breaker for calculating mode

Tags: sas

The PROC UNIVARIATE procedure calculates the mode in SAS. For tie breakers, it chooses the lowest value.

How can I modify it (if possible) or use some other means so that, when there is a tie, it ignores calculation of the mode and results in a missing value instead? That is, I only want the mode to be calculated when there is a clear majority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request a table of the modes like so:

```
ods select none;
ods output modes = weight_modes;
proc univariate data = sashelp.class modes;
  var weight;
run;
```

Then you can count the number of rows in the table via your favourite method and substitute a missing value in your downstream logic if there is more than 1 row.